# Webpack - one config for all packages in a Monorepo

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, web-component, monorepo

I'm trying to create a monorepo that will be a simple Design System using Web Components.
My goal is to have the root directory building every packages with the same WebPack config.

- Root Project

  - Packages

    - Button

      - index.js
      - dist/index.js ***<--- this is what i would like***
    - Dropdown
  - webpack.config.js
  - package.json

I would like to avoid any webpack config into each packages, it does not make sense for me.

At the end, i would like to use this monorepo in other projects by just importing the need package: `@designsystem/Button`

For now, my webpack only build at the root level and i can't find a solution, maybe you can help me with that ?

my current webpack

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path');

let entries = {
  button: "./packages/button/"
}
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    ...entries
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  ......
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a change and it now creates `dist/index.js` into each packages folder.
I dont know if it's a nice solution but i'll go with that for now:

```js
output: {
    filename(pathData) {
      const dir = pathData.chunk.entryModule.rawRequest
      return dir + "dist/index.js"
    },
    path: path.resolve(__dirname)
  },
```